# Mapping through an array and Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an array of objects like below -

```
const studentDetails = [
    {id:1, name:"Mike", stream:"Science", status:"active"},
    {id:2, name:"Kelly", stream:"Commerce", status:"inactive"},
    {id:3, name:"Bob", stream:"Law", status:"inactive"},
]
```

What I want to do is map through the array and route to another page when the status is inactive.

```
studentDetails.map(studentDetail => {
    if(studentDetail.status === 'inactive'){
        router.push("/pageB")
    }
})
```

My doubt here is that when we route to pageB when the **id** is 2, how will I continue the loop for **id=3**

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you want not to refresh the page while in the `map` loop?

Comment: @Maxali No... I want to route to the next page i.e. pageB

Answer (score 1):

Find the first inactive user using [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const studentDetails = [
    {id:1, name:"Mike", stream:"Science", status:"active"},
    {id:2, name:"Kelly", stream:"Commerce", status:"inactive"},
    {id:3, name:"Bob", stream:"Law", status:"inactive"},
]

let inactiveUser = studentDetails.find(user => user.status === "inactive");

console.log(inactiveUser);

// inactiveUser can be null, so we have to check first.
if (inactiveUser) router.push("/pageB");
```

Comment: What I really want to do is for each item in an array for which the status is **inactive**, I want to route to pageB

Comment: You have two inactive users. Do you want to `router.push` for both users?

Comment: Yes, also there can be many inactive users, but for simplicity, I have used only 3 items in an array

Comment: That means, the first `router.push` will navigate to `pageB` which i think makes the next `router.push` useless. Do you mean to navigate to pageB and send all inactive users at the sametime.

Comment: No, I want to route to pageB one at a time

Comment: Did this answer your question? Its good idea to select as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why that {id:3, status:"inactive"} is needed.
You can omit that code if it is the same as the other one except id.
Like this:

```
const studentDetails = [
    {id:1, status:"active"},
    {id:2, status:"inactive"}
]
```

Comment: it is required. actually it is a big object but for simplicity I have used only two properties. I will add more